# Error: `require': cannot load such file -- jemoji (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am using jekyll for the first time. 
I downloaded the source code from [here](https://github.com/hankquinlan/hankquinlan.github.io). When i run build and run the site using jekyll it runs well. Now I downloaded [personal theme](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/wiki/Themes) from here. After navigating to the downloaded themes folder and then building the new theme doesn't work. I get the  following error :

```
Configuration file: /home/repos/sites/personal-jekyll-theme/_config.yml
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- jemoji (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:28:in `block in require_gems'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `require_gems'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:71:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:33:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:28:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:28:in `process'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /usr/bin/jekyll:18:in `<main>'
```

Ruby Verison : ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Jekyll Version : jekyll 2.2.0

If possible please let me know where and what I am doing wrong. Is  there some rule which states that I can locally build only one rule ? As far as I searched I tried changing the port number in config.yml and also tried building different sites with  specifying their respective config files. jekyll still doesn't build and gives the same error. Thanks for your help in advance.

I also get the error which is `jekyll-feed Load Error`

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the { Personal } README under [How to run locally](https://github.com/PanosSakkos/personal-jekyll-theme#how-to-run-locally)? In particular, installing dependencies (like jemoji) seems important.

Comment: Ohh no I missed out that. thanks @Jordan. I also found out that jemoji requires ruby version greater than 2.2.4. So now I tried installing the said script but as I have ruby version which is old I will  have to update the version and then check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was resolved following the instructions in readme file and  running `./scripts/install`.

Thanks @Jordan for your help.

Comment: Make sure to accept your answer.  It's the correct answer to your quesiont, which lets future readers know that it's correct, plus you get the points and a new badge for it.

Comment: I tried however  I got the message  that I cannot accept it until 2 days. I will do as soon as I get the right to make that choice. Thanks